# PHP util-api-test-tool API throwing error: sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: php, api, curl, netbeans

I am trying to execute the API tool available here:

https://github.com/Brightspace/util-api-test-tool

However, I am getting this error and I not able to solve it:

> Error contacting server: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure.

I already updated curl, where I have:

> curl 7.62.0 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.62.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 (WinSSL) zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 WinIDN libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.34.0

My configurations are XAMPP 1.7.2 and PHP 5.3. I'm using Windows and netbeans.

I have research for this error and it seems to be very common, but I cannot find the solution for PHP. Any help is a good help.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of your problem but php 5.3 is really old and is not supported anymore, so there have been many security updates that were not applied to php 5.3. Even php 5.6 is approaching its end-of-life.

Comment: Is this curl 7.62.0 also the version that is built into PHP?  The PHP curl module also needs to be updated, which is either building a new external PHP module, or re-compiling PHP if curl is built in.  See what `<?php phpinfo() ?>` shows the curl and OpenSSL version is.

Comment: @drew010 I have curl 7.19.4. I will try to update it.

Comment: How do I update the PHP curl module? When I run phpinfo(), it returns cURL information: 7.19.4  and SSL version: OpenSSL/0.9.8k . I already to remove cURL and install it again, but it get the windows, and not the php module.

Comment: most likely curl or openssl dropped support for SSL V3, or at the very least disabled it by default (which your ancient xampp+apache server use) - what happens if you add `--sslv3` to the curl arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sslv3 (which your *ancient* xampp+apache server use) was disabled-by-default in curl version 7.39.0, which means you must add the `--sslv3` argument to connect to sslv3-servers since 7.39.0. and as stated in your post, you're using 7.62.0, so add 
the `--sslv3` argument.

... also, you should consider upgrading your apache installation.

Comment: Thanks very much. After running php.info, I have decided to install php 7 and it solved my problem.

Comment: @J.Ty the PHP version was not your problem, your apache version was the problem. but when you updated to PHP7, i guess you also updated your apache server at the same time, and that solved your problem.